# pandas dataframe add a column computing the median from the first row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column filled with floats.
I want to add a column which computes the median from the first row to the current row. I do no want to compute a rolling median but the median with all the inforamtion known ar each step.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a minimum reproducible example: a sample of your dataframe, any code you've tried and your expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check with `expanding`

```
df['your col'].expanding().median()
```